# Python: Sorting by two numbers (not ascii)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I've got list of paths for example:

```
list = ['abcdef\\02\\01.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\11.jpg',
        'abcdef\\02\\02.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\03.jpg', 'abcdef\\04\\01.jpg', ...]
```

I want to sort it first by '02' and then by '01' in 'abcdef\02\01.jpg'

I tried

```
list = ['abcdef\\02\\01.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\11.jpg',
        'abcdef\\02\\02.jpg', 'abcdef\\02\\03.jpg', 'abcdef\\04\\01.jpg', ...]

def myFunc(e):
    print(e)
    a = e.split('\\')[-2]
    b = e.split('\\')[-1][0:-4]
    return int(a+b)
list.sort(key=myFunc)
```

Output what i got from aforementioned code:

```
list = ['abcdef\\02\\1.jpg', 
       ... ,
       'abcdef\\02\\9.jpg',
       'abcdef\\04\\1.jpg',
       ... ,
       'abcdef\\04\\9.jpg',
       'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg']
```

Wanted output:

```
list = ['abcdef\\02\\1.jpg', 
       ... ,
       'abcdef\\02\\9.jpg',
       'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg',
       ... ,
       'abcdef\\02\\17.jpg',
       'abcdef\\03\\1.jpg']
```

It's sorting by ASCII. How do I sort it numerically?

Comment: How would the result differ sorting "numerically"?  The result you post isn't sorted at all.

Comment: You basically have it already, just choosing `int(a+b)` was not wise. Use `int(a), int(b)` instead. However, it may not actually make a difference, so it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Return a tuple: `return (int(a), int(b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the sorting like this,

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (int(x.split('\\')[1]), int(x.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])))

# Output
['abcdef\\02\\01.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\02.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\03.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\11.jpg',
 'abcdef\\04\\01.jpg']
```

It's essential that the format of the string remain the same to work the above code.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad you misunderstood, output in my question is what i got from aforementioned code, not wanted output

Comment: @GrenMan Please cross-check my answer again, For it matches with your **Wanted output**

Answer (score 1):

Trying to sort using `pkg_resources` package, which generally use for versions.

Code:

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version 
sorted(Mylist, key=parse_version)]
```

Output:

```
['abcdef\\02\\01.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\02.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\03.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\11.jpg',
 'abcdef\\04\\01.jpg']
```

With complicated inputs' output:

```
['abcdef\\02\\03.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\05.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\05.2.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\10.jpg',
 'abcdef\\02\\11.jpg',
 'abcdef\\03\\heloo.jpg',
 'abcdef\\04\\01.jpg']
```

Your actual input:

```
li =  ['arifureta\\03\\2.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\9.jpg','arifureta\\02\\1.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\2.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\20.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\21.jpg', 'arifureta\\03\\1.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\10.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\11.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\12.jpg']

['arifureta\\02\\1.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\2.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\9.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\10.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\11.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\12.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\20.jpg',
 'arifureta\\02\\21.jpg',
 'arifureta\\03\\1.jpg',
 'arifureta\\03\\2.jpg']
```

Comment: Somehow it didn't worked

Comment: can you please show an error you got?

Comment: it didn't had error but it sorted by ASCII ['arifureta\\02\\1.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\10.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\11.jpg', ...], wanted ['arifureta\\02\\1.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\2.jpg', 'arifureta\\02\\3.jpg']

Comment: Please update your question with your actual list and I will try.

Comment: My actual list has more than 600 items, so don't want to CTRL+C and CTRL+V it here. Anyway thanks for your help. 'Your actual input' you got that right. Sorry for trouble.